# Java 11 ZonedDateTime - Print Format

Tags: java, date-format, zoneddatetime

How could I manage to get the result of 2023-11-16T09:54:12.123 using the ZonedDateTime object in Java 11?

I wrote:

```
zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
```

and got ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME: **2023-11-16T17:25:27.1881768**

I'd like to remove the nanoseconds having only three digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways to do it:

1. Use ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME, but [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) the time to milliseconds:

```java
zdt.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
```

2. Use a [custom formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)) and keep the time unchanged:

```java
private static final var ldtMillisFormatter =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
...
zdt.format(ldtMillisFormatter)
```

Answer (score 4):

> *"... How could I manage to get the result of 2023-11-16T09:54:12.123 using the ZonedDateTime object in Java 11? ..."*

You can manually enter the values.
The list of format-specifiers can be found in the *JavaDoc*, for *[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)*.

Similarly, an outline of *ISO 8601* can be found on *Wikipedia*.
*[Wikipedia – ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)*.

```java
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String s = z.format(f);
```

Alternately, use the *[DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html)* class.

```java
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatterBuilder f
    = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral('T')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .appendLiteral('.')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3);
String s = z.format(f.toFormatter());
```

Output

```
2023-11-16T13:02:51.753
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `java.time.ZonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter)` method with a well constructed `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` object.

You can construct the `DateTimeFormatter` object with the static method `ofPattern` but seeing your sample output, the `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` should do the job

Another point is : this class is Thread-safe, so you can safely declare a static class field with your `DateTimeFormatter` with the good output pattern you want. It was not the case with previous date formatter like `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I wrote zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) and got ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME: 2023-11-16T17:25:27.1881768 I'd like to have only three digits for the TIMESTAMP not including nanoseconds.

Comment: @AdemirConstantino then take a look at what pattern is behind ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME and use a pattern without the nanoseconds.

Comment: For 2023-11-16T17:25:27.188, try `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`. You can check javadoc for more pattern and what letters mean here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html